# Parse a URL and replace variables if present

Tags: python, pytest

I have URI's specified in an xls file. I want to read that xls file, get the URI from there, parse it, and replace variables (if present) with the corresponding values, and then make an API call to that URI
For example:

```
These are a few URI's in the xls sheet:
https://api.something.com/v1/me
https://api.something.com/v1/{user_id}/account
```

(Where user_id is a variable, that has to be replaces by an appropriate value.)  is there an easy way to parse the URI and check if there's a variable present there, if yes, get the value of the variable and form a new string with the value and then use the URI to make an API call. Else use the URI as is.

Answer (score 0):

Field names can be discovered using stdlib [`string.Formatter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse):

```
>>> s = "https://api.something.com/v1/{user_id}/account"
>>> from string import Formatter
>>> parsed = Formatter().parse(s)
>>> field_names = []
>>> for literal_text, field_name, format_spec, conversion in parsed:
...     if field_name is not None:
...         field_names.append(field_name)
...         
>>> field_names
['user_id']
```

Comment: How do I replace the "field_name" user_id with the corresponding value in the URL? Basically I need to use "https://api.something.com/v1/5463hghg68/account" where "5463hghg68" is the user_id. I am looking for a more easier pythonic way, than going through the traditional string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately, Python has a built-in mechanism for handling this!

```
>>> 'https://api.something.com/v1/{user_id}/account'.format(user_id='my_id', unused_variable='xyzzy')
'https://api.something.com/v1/my_id/account'
```

Comment: for some reason, this doesnt seem to be working for me. I keep seeing *** KeyError: 'user_external_id' every time. This is my code:  if field_names_list: for each_item in field_names_list: field_name_value = endpoint_variable_dict[each_item] # (I am getting this from a dictionary. This value if valid. I checked that)
processed_api_endpoint = endpoint_in_string.format(field_name_value)

Comment: I have also tried processed_api_endpoint = endpoint_in_string.format(each_item=field_name_value) and I get the same error

Comment: @Namratha The formatter expects that every variable in the string is provided as an argument. You want `endpoint_in_string.format(**endpoint_variable_dict)`, which passes all the variables at once.